# Problems sending messages to NSMutableArrays within C-Arrays

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access, arrays

I'm currently trying to implement a pooling system, I have all the code, I just dont understand why a certain part of it doesn't work.

I have a c-array of NSMutable array made like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *poolArray[xSize][ySize];
    for (int n = 0; n < xSize; n++) 
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < ySize; m++)
        {
            poolArray[n][m] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
```

And whilst trying to access it I get the x and y coordinate of the pool and object is in and try to add it like this:

```
[poolArray[x][y] addObject:object]; //This raises a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
```

I am totally open to editing how I write this - I am aware that I could declare a NSMutableArray and use indexes of ((y * width) + x) and I may have to rewite the code like that. But preferably I dont want to have to do that as I only want to actually create the arrays I'm using so something like this:

```
if (poolArray[x][y] == nil) poolArray[x][y] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[poolArray[x][y] addObject:object];
```

This is so that it can have 'holes' so I dont have to make anything at poolArray[2][3] for example if there is nothing there.

I don't know if there is anyway that I could rewrite that with objective-c types, but if I do I'm forced to keep creating a NSMutableArray at every space, the reason I dont want to do that is because I want to get every little bit of performance I can out of the system.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and any response is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see anything wrong with the code you've provided, although a couple of ideas:

In the case where your checking poolArray[x][y] == nil have you actually reset all the values to nil when you initialize the array?

An alternative that should work, is to store the array on the heap.  You could use calloc (which will initialize the memory to 0), or malloc and memset.

The following should work:

```
NSMutableArray ***poolArray = calloc(xSize * ySize, sizeof(NSMutableArray *));

if (poolArray[x][y] == nil) poolArray[x][y] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[poolArray[x][y] addObject:object];
```

Comment: setting the objects to nil makes it work! When I did that it also made it crash at the when an autorelease pool was released, but I did read somewhere that when you dont retain the object (as I do with NSMutableArray) it is autoreleased, but I then release it at the end of my method and im guessing what made it crash was that he autorelease pool tryed to release an object that didnt exist! Thanks for the help, I've still got a few problems with the system as it's not recognising the collisions, but I'm pretty sure thats a problem elsewhere in the code as it doesnt crash now!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define xSize 10
#define ySize 10

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *poolArray[xSize][ySize];
    for (int n = 0; n < xSize; n++) 
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < ySize; m++)
        {
            poolArray[n][m] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }

    [poolArray[2][3] addObject: @"Hello"];
    [poolArray[2][3] addObject: @"world!"];
    NSLog(@"poolArray[2][3] objects: %@ %@", 
              [poolArray[2][3] objectAtIndex: 0],
              [poolArray[2][3] objectAtIndex: 1]);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

*(Yes, I know, I should release all NSMutableArray instances. Left out for brevity)*.

So there are a few things you should check:

- Is `object` a valid object, i.e. was it initialized? The `NSMutableArray` will try to `retain` the object, and if it was never initialized, that will fail miserably, or if it was `dealloc`-ed already, it will fail too.
- are `x` and `y` valid? You can easily go over the boundaries and not notice it.

Comment: Right I steped through all of the code in the debugger, as all of the sizes are calculated at runtime and xSize and ySize are 2. When going through the loops where x and y are generated they are: 1,1 1,0 0,1 0,0 so none of them are incorrect values unless I'm mistaken, and the object comes from a object in my game, I know it is initialized as without this code it runs and renders ect fine, when I did this though the code executed properly and it crashed when it got to an autorelease pool release method

Comment: Then you probably over-released (or under-retained) the object or objects you are using.

Comment: Or, much more likely, you or something autoreleased your object. That means it will function for a while, until you run into a releasePool drain or release. Just retain it where you get it and release it at an appropriate time.